# AngularJS - $httpProvider, unknown provider error when registering an interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, token, interceptor

I am trying to have a HTTP interceptor that adds a token as a http header before every request to the server.

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor',
    ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
    {
        return {
            request: function($config) {
                if( $rootScope.token)
                {
                    $config.headers['auth-token'] = $rootScope.token;
                }
                return $config;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Above, is my interceptor which looks okay to me. I then during the config state push this interceptor to the http provider, as you can see below.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when(...)
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Now when looking at my browser console log I get an error saying:
`"Unknown provider: httpRequestInterceptorProvider <- httpRequestInterceptor <- $http <- defaultErrorMessageResolver"`

It seems it can't resolve the dependency for the interceptor `httpRequestInterceptor`. Have I defined it wrong?

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: `defaultErrorMessageResolver` appears to be part of [angular-auto-validate](http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/). Have you included the `jcs-autoValidate` module as a dependency?

Comment: @Phil Yes, I have included jcs-autoValidate as a module dependency, and auto-validate works fine.
I have just updated the code snippet to show the whole app.js. I hope this helps and thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Was a silly mistake on my end, I forgot to include the factory in my index.html :/